# How to declare an ArrayList of specified type using Class object

Tags: java, class, arraylist

I want to pass a Class object to a function then declare a ArrayList of the type that class is. I am wondering how I do this.

```
public static void CreateList(Class c){
    // I want to create this array list using the variable c to define its type
    ArrayList<c> list = new ArrayList();
}
```

Comment: You can't and it makes no sense to do so.

Comment: Not in that example but if I had a List of some Superclass that I wanted to find instances of a subclass within it. public static ArrayList<? extends Object> Get Objects(ArrayList<? extends Object> list, Class c)
Stop being a party pooper all the time Sotirios

Comment: Why not use a generic method definition? `public static <T> void createList(T  c)`

Comment: Please post your actual use case in your question. The answer to your current question is: you can't.

Comment: Fair enough, stop telling everyone they're non-logical.

Comment: ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can genericize the `Class` to `Class<T>` and then use `T`:

```
public static <T> void createList(Class<T> cls) {
    ArrayList<T> = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

To expand, if you need to find the all instances of a class, or its subclasses, from a list and return the resulting values as a list, you can do:

```
public static <T> List<T> filterInstancesOf(List<?> original, Class<T> cls) {
    List<T> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o: original) {
        if (cls.isInstance(o)) {
            rv.add(cls.cast(o));
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

There were suggestions that this cannot be done, and does not make sense to do, but it does have very much sense.

It was also suggested that the `original` parameter use a bounded type, say `List<? super T>`. Again this would be useless, it would not add to the type safety, but actually render the method itself less useful.

As it is now, you can use the method to filter instances that implement an interface, for example, assuming we have

```
List<SomeClass> lst;
...
filterInstancesOf(lst, Serializable.class);
```

If the method used bounded types, this could not be used, as `SomeClass` is not the superclass of `Serializable`.

Comment: You don't even need to pass the class object as it is not used by itself.

Comment: It provides the type.

Comment: You could use a bounded type paramater to ensure that `cls` is actually a subtype of the element type of the list.

Comment: Yes but it is not needed either; now the cls can be an interface too.

Comment: You're right in that what you have is more flexible in that it allows an interface. But the OP's comment asked about a subclass. A bounded type parameter (note, not a bounded wildcard) could enforce the restriction to a subclass at compile time, if that's really what the OP wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
Array.newInstance(Class<?> componentType, int length)
```

and then create a list from it:

```
Arrays.asList(array)
```

Comment: This is not an `ArrayList`

Comment: `@SafeVarargs
    @SuppressWarnings("varargs")
    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
        return new ArrayList<>(a);
    }`

Comment: The `ArrayList` that `Arrays.asList` creates is a nested class of `Arrays`. That is, it's a `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` and not a `java.util.ArrayList`. They differ in that the list returned by `Arrays.asList` does not permit elements to be inserted or removed. (Yeah, this is really confusing.)